# Py2exe (Python Pygame) - Is there not an easier way?

Tags: python, pygame, exe, py2exe

I just checked the wiki and realized you need to input a tonne of code to change a python file containing pygame code to an exe. Is there not an easier way? Shouldn't it just be an exe file that you just open and imput what you want to change and where to save the exe to?

Comment: ...is there not an easier way *for what*? You should rephrase your question and clarify what you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I would recommend using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). All you have to do it go into the pyinstaller directory, and then run:

```
python pyinstaller.py /link/to/your/program
```

which should then make a directory in the pyinstaller directory named after your .py file. In that file you will have a build folder and a dist folder. The dist is the one of interest and will have your .exe in it.